# "undefined reference to vtable" error when setting object pointer to 0 (null), no error if left undefined

Tags: c++, pointers, null, vtable

I have a very simple class

```
class XT_FilterNoise_Class 
{
  public:
};
```

It was more complex but I stripped everything out trying to track down the problem leaving just the skeleton above.

I create a pointer to an object of this class in this class:

```
class XT_PlayListItem_Class
{   
  public:
  XT_PlayListItem_Class *PreviousItem=0;        
  XT_PlayListItem_Class *NextItem=0;    
  XT_FilterNoise_Class *Filter=0;           // Here is the pointer begin created
  bool Playing=false;                           
  uint32_t PlayingTime;                     
  uint32_t TimeElapsed;                     
  uint32_t TimeLeft;                                
  char Name[32];                                    
  uint8_t LastValue;                            
  uint8_t Volume;                           

  virtual uint8_t NextByte();                   
  virtual void Init();                      
};
```

When I try to compile I get the error

undefined reference to `vtable for XT_PlayListItem_Class'

If I change the line

```
XT_FilterNoise_Class *Filter=0;
```

to

```
XT_FilterNoise_Class *Filter;
```

I get no error. I thought vtable was something to do with virtual methods (from my researching this error). Now originally I did have a virtual function in the FilterNoise class but all that and the definitions were removed when trying to get to the root of the error leaving this just bare bones structure.

As you can see I set other pointers to 0 and don't understand why I cannot do the same with this one. The compiler is GCC within the Arduino environment.

I could define the pointer to null (0) elsewhere in code I think but I don't want to go past this point without understanding what's going on. Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Undefined reference" is a linker error. How are you compiling and linking your code?

Comment: Can you try `nullptr`  instead of `0` and report the result.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in C or C++ coding and I'm just using the Arduino IDE to handle all linking and compiling (GCC based I believe) as this is part of code for an embedded MCU. I tried nullptr but the error was the same. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: OK, voting to close for lacking a [mcve], then.

Comment: In my experience this isn't an error with your code, it's an error in your build procedures. Make sure you delete all intermediate files in your project and then rebuild everything.

Comment: Thank you for the response, understand the need to close if it cannot be replicated. It does seem to be perhaps some issue with the build, working on clearing out for a clean build and further testing.

Comment: A [mcve] probably will need to contain your various files, stripped to the bare minimum. The extraneous fields should be dropped.